# In memory database wrapper for system.data.sqlite

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am using system.data.sqlite for in memory testing, and i wanted to know if any of you got a link or knowledge for a open source project that simply create database and tables ?

For example :

```
InMemoryDB db = new  InMemoryDB();
Table t = new Table("myTable");
t.Add(new Coloum("Uid",DbType.VarChar,PrimeryKey = true));
db.Add(t);
```

or even a better idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `"Data Source=:memory:"` as your connection string, and manipulate the DB directly in SQL

Comment: do you think if i create some generic project like that it would be helpful for developers ?

Comment: A project to do what? create the DB schema from code? There are already tools that can do it, ORMs like Entity Framework or NHibernate

Comment: For some reason, this fails if I have the spaces around the `=` but it works fine if I use `"Data Source=:memory:"`

Comment: @default.kramer, you're right, there was an error in my syntax. I fixed it.